# name.replace is not a function in mat table with dynamic columns

Tags: typescript, angular8, mat-table

I need to use a mat table with dynamic columns, but I get this error:

```
> ERROR TypeError: name.replace is not a function
>     at MatColumnDef.set name [as name] (table.js:175)
>     at updateProp (core.js:32189)
>     at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31867)
>     at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44367)
>     at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44306)
>     at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:45328)
>     at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:45271)
>     at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (TableComponent.html:3)
>     at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:45259)
>     at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44271)
```

In my ts I've declared:

```
tableConfigurations = {
    dataSource: [],
      columns: [{
        name: 'first'
      },
      {
        name: 'second'
      },
      {
        name: 'third'
      },
      {
        name: 'fourth'
      },
      {
        name: 'fifth'
      }]
  }
```

and in html I have:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="tableConfigurations.dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of tableConfigurations.columns">

    <ng-container>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column.name}} </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableConfigurations.columns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableConfigurations.columns;"></tr>

</table>
```

[This is the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bp1pbh) with the current code I have. As you can see in the console, there is the same error. I don't get what I'm missing.

Comment: Hi! Your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder now I've added the code. I thought I could directly link the stackblitz to have the working example ready right there.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code on-site. It would help people help you if you made it runnable (**on**-site).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was in

```
columns: [{ name: 'first' }, {name: 'second'}, ... ]
```

There are two approaches that you can follow:

1. The columns array will change into string array like:

   `columns: ['first', 'second', ... ]`

Angular material table display columns have to be string Array in order columns to be parsed.

2. Add a variable for coverting the columns array into string array for displaying it correctly

`displayedColumns: any[] = this.tableConfigurations.columns.map(col => col.name);`

**Finally:**

Your html will be like:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="tableConfigurations.dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column.name" *ngFor="let column of tableConfigurations.columns;">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column.name}}</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column.name]}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>

</table>
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-azyjr4)